# aggregate + mean returns wrong result

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

Using R, I am about to calculate groupwise means with `aggregate(..., mean)`. The mean return however is wrong.

```
testdata <-read.table(text="
a  b    c   d   year
2   10  1   NA  1998
1   7   NA  NA  1998
4   6   NA  NA  1998
2   2   NA  NA  1998
4   3   2   1   1998
2   6   NA  NA  1998
3   NA  NA  NA  1998
2   7   NA  3   1998
1   8   NA  4   1998
2   7   2   5   1998
1   NA  NA  4   1998
2   5   NA  6   1998
2   4   NA  NA  1998
3   11  2   7   1998
1   18  4   10  1998
3   12  7   5   1998
2   17  NA  NA  1998
2   11  4   5   1998
1   3   1   1   1998
3   5   1   3   1998
",header=TRUE,sep="")
aggregate(. ~ year, testdata,
          function(x) c(mean = round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2)))
colMeans(subset(testdata, year=="1998", select=d), na.rm=TRUE)
```

`aggregate` says the mean of `d` for group `1998` is 4.62, but it is 4.5.

Reducing the data to one column only, `aggregate` gets it right:

```
aggregate(. ~ year, test[4:5],
          function(x) c(mean = round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2)))
```

What's wrong with my `aggregate()` + `mean()` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

aggregate is taking out your rows containing NAs in any column before passing it to the mean function. Try running your aggregate call without `na.rm=TRUE` - it will still work.

To fix this, you need to change the default na.action in aggregate to na.pass:

```
aggregate(. ~ year, testdata,
          function(x) c(mean = round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2)), na.action = na.pass)


  year    a    b    c   d
1 1998 2.15 7.89 2.67 4.5
```

Comment: Nice. Or skip the formula interface altogether, which is what introduces the `na.omit` by default - `aggregate(testdata[c("a","b","c","d")],testdata["year"],mean,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: This approach also works to allow mean, max, min, etc to be calculated on the subset of data within a group (e.g., timeframe) that has numeric values, ignoring the data in that group that is NA. Great!